# Iphone Flip UIimages

Tags: iphone

i'm about to developp a memory game for children, and i want to know how to flip between two UIImage with animation?
any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a view (`UIView`) that will contain the displayed image view and swap between them on touch (either implement a touch events or use a button above the image views or use buttons instead of image views).

Next is a sample code for swapping 2 image views inside one container view (as described above):

```
// setup the animation group
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(transitionDidStop:finished:context:)];

// swap the views and transition
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:containerView cache:YES];

[imageView1 removeFromSuperview];
[containerView addSubview:imageView2];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can also see the Elements sample project by Apple with a working example...